# Resetting an Angular Reactive Form without triggering error rendering?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

In [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-login-form-learning?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin-form.component.ts) the login form username field renders in red after login is clicked, even though the form is reset like this:

```
  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.onLogin.emit(this.form.value);
      this.form.reset();
      this.form.markAsPristine();
      this.form.markAsUntouched();
      this.form.setErrors(null);
    }
  }
```

How do we keep the username field from painting red?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the required validator to your form in order to check the validation otherwise it will always return true for `this.form.valid`. It should be as follows :

```
 form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  });
```

Note : be sure you imported Validators from @angular/forms

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

and the error message should not be send from parent element because your are checking for errors when submitting the form so the submit() method should be as follows :

```
submit() {
if (this.form.valid && this.form.touched) {
    this.error = ''
    this.submitEM.emit(this.form.value);
}else{
    this.error = 'Username or password invalid'
}
```

}

Note : remove Input decorator for error message because the validation check is done in child component.

```
error: string | null;
```

[Click here for demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-login-form-learning-nzbvgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin-form.component.ts)

Comment: HI @Viswa - Welcome to SO.  The answer comes close, except for that if you add `form.reset()` after submitting the form, all the fields turn red ...

Comment: Hi @Ole - the fields turn red because of the default behavior of mat-form-field of Angular Material when the form is being reset `mat-form-field-invalid` class is being added to the form because the form is empty.

Comment: Hi  @Viswa - Indeed yes - I was thinking that calling `markAsUntouched();` would remove it, but apparently not ...